# CustomMaterialDataPicker to select just one day

Tags: android, kotlin

I was developing an App where I need to implement the following component of android library: RangeDateSelector.

My main goal is limit the selection to just one day, instead of allow pick a range of days.

To  do this I use my CustomDataPicker, which allow to select a range of dates:

CustomMaterialDatePicker

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
class CustomMaterialDatePicker : RangeDateSelector() {

    private var first = true
    private var firstDate: Long? = null

    override fun select(selection: Long) {
        if (first || selection < firstDate!!) {
            super.select(selection)
            super.select(selection)
            firstDate = selection
            first = false
        } else {
            super.select(firstDate!!)
            super.select(selection)
            if (selection != firstDate) {
                first = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And create another data picker, which don't allow this multiple selection:

CustomMaterialDatePickerOneDay

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
class CustomMaterialDatePickerOneDay : RangeDateSelector() {

    private var first = true
    private var firstDate: Long? = null

    override fun select(selection: Long) {
        if (first) {
            super.select(selection)
            super.select(selection)
            firstDate = selection
            first = false
        }
    }
}
```

The main goal is to when I set the positive listener to the picker, this allow to manage just one day, and not a Pair of those.

Although I try to implement this solution like this, I'm still getting Pair<Long,Long> instead just Long

[image]

So if you are in knowledge of some way to manage this situation, take thanks in advance !

[EDIT]

The main goal of this questions is make that the RangeDataPicker, DON'T allow select more than one day, as this:

[image]

Comment: One day mean why you need to customise?  Default picker will allow one day only?. Can you provide more context?

Comment: I mean customise to only be able to select one day, instead of select a range of those, so I need that when yo set the listener to the picker, manage a Long, and not a Pair<Long,Long>

Comment: Default picker providing only one day right.. it's already available... I can't get you...

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify

Comment: Still you're meaning one day only... what exactly you want !?Ex: 18 don't allow more or between one day like 18 to 20

Comment: What I want is the component just let you select one day, not a range of days, but I don't find a way to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246602/discussion-between-gobu-csg-and-manuel-lucas).